# Reason why doing these steps on squares always results in 8

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't think this will be an especially deep question but I don't have the strongest mathematical background so I'm wonder what in essence the steps I'm doing equate to.

So if I have a square with 1x1 tile and want to expand it evenly I will need to add 8 more tiles for a 9x9 square of tiles.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 size & 1x1 & 3x3 & 5x5 & 7x7 & 9x9 & 11x11 \\ \hline
 total & 1 & 9 & 25 & 49 & 81 & 121 \\ \hline
 n - n_{-1} & & 8 & 16 & 24 & 32 & 40 \\ \hline
\end{array}

If I then take the difference between each step, I always get 8.
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 size & 1x1 & 3x3 & 5x5 & 7x7 & 9x9 & 11x11 \\ \hline
 total & 1 & 9 & 25 & 49 & 81 & 121 \\ \hline
 n - n_{-1}&& 8 & 16 & 24 & 32 & 40 \\ \hline
 && & 8 & 8 & 8 & 8 \\ \hline
\end{array}

So my question is why does this always end in 8. My guess is something to do with powers of 2 going on here since $2^3=8$

Comment: A closely related fact is that $n^2$ is equal to the sum of the first $n$ positive odd numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
N_0(n)=n^2\\
N_1(n)=N_0(n)-N_0(n-2)=n^2-(n-2)^2=4n-4\\
N_2(n)=N_1(n)-N_1(n-2)=4n-4-(4(n-2)-4)=8
$$

Or instead of formulas you can look at this picture:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Thought it might be that simple!

Comment: I have also added a picture for you.

Answer (score 1):

What you have come across is called the calculus of finite differences. If $P(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients, it turns out that taking differences as you did, repeatedly, will eventually result in a row of the same number.

For example, if $P(x)=x^3$, then you get, starting with $P(1), P(2), P(3), \dots$

$\begin{array}{c}
 1 &&  8 && 27 && 64 && 125 && 216 && 343 && 512 && 729 \dots \\
    &  7 && 19 && 37 &&  61 &&  91 && 127 && 169 && 217 \dots \\
         && 12 && 18 &&  24 &&  30 &&  36 &&  42 &&  48 \dots \\
               &&& 6 &&   6 &&   6 &&   6 &&   6 &&   6 \dots
\end{array}$

Comment: Oh very interesting thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to know what the final row will be? And  if I am assuming correctly the amount of times you must subtract is related to the power you use?

Comment: Yes, an order $n$ polynomial will require $n$ differences. The study of finite differences is a "finite" way of studying differential equations. What I showed you is just a very small piece of a much richer subject.

Answer (score 1):

Great observation!

Notice each tile edge is two more than that previous.

So you want to know why $[(n+4)^2 - (n+2)^2] - [(n+2)^2 - n^2] = 8$.

Notice:  The difference between two odd squares is $(k+2)^2 -k^2 = (k^2 + 4k + 4) - k^2 =4k +4$.

So $[(n+4)^2 - (n+2)^2] - [(n+2)^2 - n^2]=[4(n+2)+4]-[4n+4]$

And the difference between the difference of two odd squares is therefore $[4(n+2)+4]-[4n+4] = (4n - 4n) + 4*2 + (4-4) = 4*2 =8$.

Comment: Thanks. This is why my lack of math skills held me back. I didn't quite know how to express any of these things as a function.